# Where can I find public domain images of the latest Apple products for commercial use?

Tags: apple-store

I would like to use the images from Apple websites and don’t know how to contact and get permission to use some images from Apple.

Are there ways to get written permission to use these images commercially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should be able to find Apple product images on the official website along with applicable license and applicable usage guidelines/restrictions. However, they are all copyrighted and trademark protected, so you want a lawyer to advise you and not people on the internet, no matter how reasonable we seem.

Most comprehensive information is on Apple’s legal page covering Apple Intellectual Property: https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/

Once you are set on trademark, copyright and permitted uses, other places to look are:

1. [Apple Newsroom Archive](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/archive/): Search for the product announcement news item for the product you are looking for (e.g. here's the [link](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2019/11/apple-introduces-16-inch-macbook-pro-the-worlds-best-pro-notebook/) to the news item for the recently announced 16" MacBook Pro), and you'd find the images made available by Apple.
2. [App Store Marketing Resources and Identity Guidelines Webpage](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#section-products): You can find the product image templates here, with blank screens. The images can be used as per the terms of license for marketing your own software.

The contact information for Apple PR personnel is also generally made available with the Newsroom item. You can also find the relevant contact information on the [Apple Contact Us](https://www.apple.com/contact/) webpage.